# gtkmm load from resource plain text file

Tags: c++, gtkmm

I have a simple resource xml file looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<gresources>
    <gresource prefix="ui"> 
        <file preprocess="xml-stripblanks">ui.glade</file>
    </gresource>
    <gresource prefix="text-data">
        <file>definitions.txt</file>
    </gresource>
</gresources>
```

And UI loaded without problem

> refBuilder->add_from_resource("/ui/ui.glade");

But I do not know how to load and read the text file that is defined in the resource file as "definition.txt".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are able to retrieve the file contents with one of two static methods of Gio::Resource class: [open_stream_global](https://developer.gnome.org/glibmm/stable/classGio_1_1Resource.html#a086b7d2e2ddc80a8299f554e40c11bf3) or [lookup_data_global](https://developer.gnome.org/glibmm/stable/classGio_1_1Resource.html#a4808bada1bdd91a0fea676278e228c86). Here are their signatures:

- `Glib::RefPtr< InputStream > open_stream_global (const std::string& path, ResourceLookupFlags lookup_flags=RESOURCE_LOOKUP_FLAGS_NONE)`
- `Glib::RefPtr< const Glib::Bytes > lookup_data_global (const std::string& path, ResourceLookupFlags lookup_flags=RESOURCE_LOOKUP_FLAGS_NONE)`

As you can see, the difference between them is how you access data: via a [Gio stream class](https://developer.gnome.org/glibmm/stable/classGio_1_1InputStream.html) or [Glib::Bytes](https://developer.gnome.org/glibmm/stable/classGlib_1_1Bytes.html) (a "data array": byte contents + length).